# How to use double as a function in java?

Tags: java

I don't know how to debug it

```java
public class Triangle {
  
    double a;
    double b;
    
    public Triangle(double a1, double b1) {
        a = a1;
        b = b1;
    } 
   
    public void PrintInfo() {
       
        System.out.println("Triangle: ");
        double c = get_c;

        System.out.format("a = %f\nb = %f\nc = %f\n",a ,b ,c);

    }
        public double get_c() {
            double c =Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);

            return c;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Ghh {
   
 public static void main(String[] args) {
          
          Triangle T = new Triangle(3 , 4);
          T.PrintInfo();     
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What does the program supposed to do>

Comment: It will measure the size of third side of a Triangle

Comment: In Java a method call needs to be written as the name of the method followed by parenthesis containing the parameters (if any). So it is not `double c = get_c;`, it is `double c = get_c();`

Comment: You should always include the exact compiler error along with telling us where the error is (line numbers aren't visible here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the line below:

```
double c = get_c;
```

With

```
double c = get_c();
```

That's how to call methods in java. In case your method has arguments, you simply supply the parameters inside the parentheses.